# How i can find which request method is used for paypal integration

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, omnipay, symfony-2.7

i m new to **paypal integration** can any one please help me with how i can find which **request method** **is used  for paypal itegration.**
when i click on pay button following calles made :

1. logtimeout(GET)
2. auth?(GET)
3. setbuyer(POST)
4. p1(POST)
5. p2(POST)

So, i m confuse which method is actually making call to paypal for payment.
Paypal is Discontinuing GET method so i want to chang **GET to POST**

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Can you share some code for your paypal button?

Comment: Does this question relate to one of the omnipay gateways for PayPal? I ask because I see you have tagged the question with omnipay. In general I would use the PayPal REST gateway if you are using omnipay, it uses POST methods for all of the communications to the gateway.

Comment: @delatbabel First thanks for the answer, Yes your right I m using **omnipay/PayPal**. I m using PayPal_Express checkout so **is their need to convert request methods?** one more questions can you please explain to me how flow work in the omnipay gateway for PayPal_Express? In next project, i will surely use PayPal REST Gateway.

Comment: @bluepnume Thanks for an answer, On PayPal button, I m submitting form data to Omnipay bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the PayPal Express omnipay gateway (PayPal_Express) then all of the calls in that gateway are POST calls. There are no GET calls in use, they were all converted to POST calls some time ago when PayPal announced that they were deprecating the use of GET calls.

In general I would advise use of the PayPal_REST gateway rather than PayPal_Express, the calls are more up to date and the documentation is better. You can go into your developer site for PayPal and obtain API keys for REST which you can use alongside your Express keys while you change over.

Comment: As you said **There are no GET calls in use, they were all converted to POST calls some time ago when PayPal announced that they were deprecating the use of GET calls.**
I m using 
 "omnipay/omnipay": "~2.0",
  "omnipay/authorizenet": "~2.0",
This versions,
 Does I need to change ? anything?

Comment: No you do not need to change anything, you should be all set to go with those versions.

Comment: Thank you so much for guiding me.